# Detect if USTREAM is broadcasting (on-air)

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, video-streaming, embedded-video

What is the best way to detect if a broadcast is live coming from USTREAM? I've got a church site that uses USTREAM and they would like to have the embeded player show up when the broadcast is live and disappear when the broadcast is off-air.

Is this possible with ColdFusion or some kind of javascript/ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.ustream.tv/docs

Comment: I'm not kidding when I say I went looking for that. Thanks for posting the link. My apologies for being obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://api.ustream.tv/html/channel/all/search/title:eq:yourChannelName?key=yourDevkey
```

found all the way at the bottom of the page. Thanks a lot ustream having such an easy API to be able to understand. #not